# Elastic Beanstalk - dashboard vs eb tool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there any relationship whatsoever between the environments and applications managed with the `eb` Elastic Beanstalk command line tool and the ones managed with the Amazon account web dashboard? I've just spent about 2 hours of my life assuming they *were* related and am beginning to suspect they are completely independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think they are independent? Could it be that you connect to two different regions?

Make sure dropdown in web console and region switch in `eb` point to the same region:

```
--region REGION       AWS Elastic Beanstalk region (i.e., us-east-1).
```

Comment: I didn't intend to connect to two regions, I just didn't see the dropdown in the top right limiting the console to a specific region. I really, really, really wish the documentation had made some kind of mention of that.

Comment: I agree with you on the documentation. I'm glad it worked out at the end.